# Jenkins: How to use a custom plugin in Declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've checked the [Pipeline syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) page of Jenkins. It's all about the declarative pipeline and I see the syntax.

Can you achieve the same with the declarative Pipeline then with the scripted Pipeline? When I use the generator for the scripted pipeline I see immediately how I can import plugins, use/configure them.

But with the Declarative pipeline I don't see that. I see some main functions and a lot of sh usage.

For example: parameter (and I can add some parameters).
But there is some string validation parameter plugin. When I download this plugin I'm able to use it in the Scripted Pipeline etc. But I don't see how I can use this for my Declarative Pipeline.

This I'm facing this use case a lot. Is it possible to use every plugin with a Declarative Pipeline or not? (it seems possible with Scripted Pipeline)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read most of the parameter types in the `environment` section of your Declarative Pipeline.

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    environment { 
        USER_CRED = credentials('my-user-cred') 
        USER_NAME = string('my-user-name')
        ACTIVE = booleanParam('active')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo ${USER_NAME} - ${USER_CRED} - ${ACTIVE}'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You also have `choice`, `file`, `password`, `run` and `text` (and probably other defined in plugins instead of core). Unfortunately [the plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Validating+String+Parameter+Plugin) I think you are talking about does not support this use format (as it does not defines a `@Symbol` on [its implementation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/validating-string-parameter-plugin/blob/ff138b10ba99852fde395ca2c9e54175ccdb8791/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/validating_string_parameter/ValidatingStringParameterDefinition.java#L94).

Using declarative is preferable over scripted, but if you can't do something with declarative, then you can use the `script` tag to execute scripted code:

```
stages {
    stage('Stage 1') {
        steps {
            script {
              // scripted code as in non-declarative
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a `run`-type parameter?

Comment: It's this: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/fd932fef98a95e12876f2f0238d8e269467de8e9/war/src/main/webapp/help/parameter/run.html